# spinner android set selection alternative

Tags: android, spinner

I created 2 Spinners and I filled them with an array of numbers. What I want is that the user chooses the number they want on the first one, and then I save it to a variable that I use to populate the dropdown list of the second one with values that start after that number. How can I do this? How can I change the text in the second spinner to start with the number chosen.

I have this, I store the item of the Spinner on the variable x, and I want a second Spinner to start with that variable.

```
mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewGuiaActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        establist));

                // Spinner on item click listener
                mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Locate the textviews in activity_main.xml

                        arg0.setSelection(5);

                        x = estab.get(position).getID();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
```

the arg0.setSelection(5), does the trick but it dont let me choose another value when i click on a diferent item of the spinner how can i change this.

Comment: Are you using same list of values for both list views?

Comment: Its okay, get the index value after first Spinner's setOnItemSelectedListener called, create a List on run time for your second spinner and get values from n to size of list view, pass that list in second spinner adapter. This will work perfect.

Comment: isnt there a method that only changes the starting item of the spinner insted of the setSelection